# How to create eclipse project to debug Javascript on web page

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have the latest Eclipse (helios) installation.  I have Javascript development tools installed.

How do I create a workspace/project so that I can step through some javascript code?  The project should be an html page with an associated javascript file.

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: I am adding this as a comment instead of an answer because it is not a direct answer to your question. On Mac I use Firefox, Safari, and Chrome each of which have tools built in for stepping through code. On Windows, the above three exist with their own tools, and for IE I use Visual Web Develop Express 2010 (free).

Comment: I just found out that IE 8 on Windows has a built in script debugger.  I can use this to find problems in my code.

Answer (score 0):

chrome has a good debuging tool too. For more complex HTML / javascript developmet a like to use the WebStorm IDE. You can set breakpoints direct in the IDE.